# What is the network type that exibits hight bandwidth at the end nodes?

Tags: networking

What is the network type that exibits high bandwidth at the end nodes and what is the network type that exibits high latency at the end nodes?
Can you help me please?

Comment: Practically all networks. Your Ethernet or wifi is a lot faster than your DSL or ADSL to your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Bandwidth and latency have little to do with each other.  A network with a high bandwidth can experience high latency and vice versa.